# Fix a react state variable even upon refresh

Tags: reactjs

How do i set the value of  state variable to not go to the default value on refresh? Let's say im keeping a state variable theme,user can change it by toggle button.But when the refresh is done theme value goes to it's default value 'light' instead of 'dark'

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with localStorage

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var selectedOption = localStorage.getItem( 'SelectedOption' ) || 1;

    return {
        selectedOption: selectedOption
    };
},

setSelectedOption: function( option ) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'SelectedOption', option );
    this.setState( { selectedOption: option } );
}
```